# I deleted my own question, can I get it back?

Tags: support

I deleted my question, because I saw a big flaw in it and didn't want a ton of downvotes.. I fixed it (it still had the option), and when I clicked 'OK' it said the question had been deleted (obviously). Can I find this question so that I can re open it?

Comment: if you're asking about http://superuser.com/questions/403072/keyboard-mouse-shortcuts-that-make-life-easier it ain't going to last long

Comment: Sathya, that would be helpful if I could actually view the link

Comment: You should be able to view your own deleted questions. What happens when you click Sathya's link? For reference, it's "Keyboard / mouse shortcuts that make life easier" and a really horribly *not constructive* question.

Comment: I get Page not Found - This question was voluntarily removed by the author – that's you! We couldn't find the page you requested. But we haven't looked inside your computer for it. Yet.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know the behavior was changed. It wasn't like this when I was below 10k rep (and couldn't see all deleted questions).

Comment: I'll explain really quick why it's a bad question, since you re-posted it: Any number of answers is valid, and necessarily incomplete, since you include individual applications (making it *overly broad*, therefore **not a real question**). The deciding factor will be popularity of the mentioned shortcuts, i.e. *polling* (making it **not constructive**). It's also possible that there will be *arguments and debate* about the usefulness of individual shortcuts, since you provide no criteria at all that could be used to judge answers. Furthermore, which shortcuts are useful is highly *subjective*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [view it only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/133693) if you have 10k rep or more, provided you have a link to the question.

> #### How can I undelete one of my posts?
>
> Self-deleted answers can be viewed, edited, and undeleted by their
> original authors.
>
> For questions, this is generally not possible, except in these two
> situations:
>
> - Immediately after you delete a question, it will change color to indicate that it is deleted, and an undelete link will appear. If you
>   have less than 10k reputation, you will not be able to see the link —
>   or any part of the question — after you leave the page.
> - If and when you reach 10k reputation on a site, you see all of that site's deleted posts. They remain unsearchable, but if you know the
>   URL of your deleted question or marked it as a "favorite" before
>   deleting it, you can visit it directly and use the undelete link. If
>   you were not the deleter, you may need to wait for other 10k users to
>   cast additional undelete votes.
>
> If neither of these situations applies to you, you can ask a moderator
> to undelete one of your questions by flagging one of your other posts
> and writing a note in the "other" section explaining the situation.